# Gmail "send mail as" in my primary account creating/sending a copy to my secondary account

Tags: gmail

I have two gmail accounts, primary A, and secondary B.  I receive email sent to account B that is automatically forwarded to A (via Gmail's auto-forwarding or pop3). Then I reply in account A using gmail's 'send mail as' feature, I can send mail as if I was in account B back to the original sender.

The piece that I want to put all together is having a copy of my sent email saved in account B even though I am signed into and using account A.

If I look at account B, I wish to see the conversation between original sender and account A (which is sending mail as if it was account B).

Comment: If your email is being forwarded to account A, I don't think there would be a way to send your sent mail to account B, because that would mean bypassing the forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I see to this is BCCing account B on every email you send as account B from within account A. The only issues I see are:

- You have to add BCC every time
- They won't automatically show up in account B's Sent Mail label, but instead in the Inbox

To get around that second issue, you should be able to set a filter in account B to put email where account B is both sender and BCCed into the IMAP/Sent folder (can't filter into Sent Mail directly).

One side note is that Gmail is smart enough to not re-forward the email back to account A's inbox.

Another option would be resorting to using IMAP to manually copy messages back and forth, but that would be a lot less elegant and a lot more work.